# HTML5 image zoom in/out

Tags: html, image, image-processing, zooming

I have been asked to find ways to do zoom in/out in HTML5. I am new to html5 and would like some direction on this. Is there anything specific in html5 that allows to do zooming? I have done some research but do not see anything that jumps out.

Are there any plugins that are specifically tailored to HTML5 for the purpose of zooming? I need to zoom in on a image (jpg).

Comment: Googling `html5 image zoom in/out` yields plenty of useful-looking results. With almost 6,000 reputation points, you should know that's always the very first step.

Comment: I need a useful result, not a useful-looking one. Hence I am asking here on a question/answer site. What I should and should not know is not relevant here.

Comment: As it stands, this looks like a lazy question with no visible prior research, which is not a good fit for this site. What exactly about the many results does not work for you?

Comment: I do not see any plugins for zooming specifically tailored to html5. There are many jquery plugins, yes, but no html5 ones. Thus, I have asked here what people are using so I don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to zoom? An image? An element? An entire page? [This example](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-scaling-a-drawing-with-plus-and-minus-buttons/) works with a `canvas` element but that may not be not what you want.

Comment: edited the question body

Comment: Check out http://techslides.com/image-zoom-drag-and-crop-with-html5, it may have some pointers

Comment: thanks! can you put it as an answer? great start

Answer (score 2):

I think the CSS "background-size" property is the best solution.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Embed the image with "background: url()" in a HTMLElement and just change the background-size value.

**CSS**

```
body
{
    background: url(http://www.w3.org/html/logo/img/html5-topper.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%; /* change this property*/
    background-position-x: 0px;
    background-position-y: 0px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input
    type="range" min="10" max="500" value="100"
    oninput="document.body.style.backgroundSize = this.value + '%';"
>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ktgf6swr